# Подскажите как сделать редирект 301й со страницы

Tags: joomla

Подскажите как сделать редирект 301й со страницы

http://site.ua/index.php на http://site.ua/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|htm|html|shtml|asp|aspx)\    HTTP/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ua$
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|htm|html|shtml|asp|aspx)$ http://site.ua/ [R=301,L]
```

Вот пример, но тут не только с index.php делает редирект но и с остальных популярных типов страниц.
А если только php, то вот.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\    HTTP/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ua$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://site.ua/ [R=301,L]
```